# How should I handle an fsync exception from libSystem.B.dylib?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, sigabrt, fsync

I got a crash report with this stack trace:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  1

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib  0x30d2ac98 fsync + 8
1   libsqlite3.dylib   0x3617b52a _sqlite3_purgeEligiblePagerCacheMemory + 1626
2   libsqlite3.dylib   0x3617b54e _sqlite3_purgeEligiblePagerCacheMemory + 1662
3   libsqlite3.dylib   0x36172824 sqlite3_db_status + 1072
4   libsqlite3.dylib   0x3619c5dc sqlite3_create_function16 + 38176
5   libsqlite3.dylib   0x3619c63c sqlite3_create_function16 + 38272
6   libsqlite3.dylib   0x3619cc50 sqlite3_create_function16 + 39828
7   libsqlite3.dylib   0x361b0d96 fts3DbExec + 21826
8   libsqlite3.dylib   0x36171de4 sqlite3_step + 56
9   DesignScene        0x0000d750 -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:withArgumentsInArray:orVAList:] (FMDatabase.m:488)
```

Shame to get an fsync exception, but shit happens, right? My question is, how best should I handle this exception? Wrap it in a `@try/@catch` block?

---

**Update:** The crash was in thread 1. Here's the complete trace from Thread 1:

```
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d30974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dda704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dda174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dd9b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e24a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d76970 start_wqthread + 0
```

All I can say is, WTF? Could there have been some sort of weird system issue here? ’Cause I don't see any of my own code in that trace.

Comment: If you're actually getting an exception, you should include the text of the exception in your question. If you're not getting an exception, `@try/@catch` probably won't help.

Comment: Or try to set a breakpoint in GDB, if you know how to use it...

Comment: @Anomie—No exception message other than what you see here.

Comment: @Macmade—No way to set a breakpoint. This only happened on a device where the app was running in the background overnight. The user was in another app in the morning, and when he switched to my app, got this bizarre crash. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was a system-level exception from iOS. Not much to be done about it. Freakish stuff happens, right?